# When plotting phylogeny using plotBranchbyTrait, the colour intensity which indicates a trait value does not correspond with values in my data

Tags: r

I am trying to plot a phylogeny tree and have the colours of the branches correspond to a continuous trait of the species. I am using the function  plotBranchbyTrait from the phytools package in R to do it but the colour intensity which indicates the degree of the trait (amount of sediment in diet in my case) for each species do not all correspond to my data. Is plotBranchbyTrait actually using the values of the trait for the species to indicate colour or is it colouring by the inverse of that trait value because the plotted colour intensities seem to show that. Any other suggestions to do this would be appreciated.

Here is an example of my code:

`birdtree <- read.nexus("output.nex") # my pruned phylogeny tree downloaded from BirdTree.org`

`rootedtree <- maxCladeCred(birdtree,tree = TRUE, rooted = TRUE) # here you root the tree`

`diet_averages <- read.csv("species diet averages.csv",header=TRUE, na.strings=c("", "n/a")) # my data showing percent of seed in diet`

`str(diet_averages)`

`data.frame': 123 obs. of  2 variables:`

`$ binomial: chr  "Accipiter_cooperii" "Accipiter_gentilis" "Accipiter_melanoleucus" "Acridotheres_tristis" ...`

`$ seeds   : num  0 0 0 17.6 0 0 0 38.4 0 0 ...`

`plotBranchbyTrait(rootedtree, mydata$seeds, palette = "rainbow")`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. 'plotBranchbyTrait' has a problematic mapping routine that mixes up nodes and edges when mapping all edges AND tips.

This is a workaround, which ignores the edge data (creating new edge values with 'plotBranchbyTrait'):

```
MapData<-mydata$seeds
MapData<-MapData[1:length(rootedtree$tip.label)] # assuming that the rows 1:x correspond to the taxa in the tree
names(MapData)<-rootedtree$tip.label
plotBranchbyTrait(rootedtree, MapData, palette = "rainbow", mode="tips")
```

After considerable searching I also found the root of the problem. When mapping a complete data set, including edge data, 'plotBranchbyTrait' internally reorders the input vector according to the "rootedtree$edge".
You can search the tree to identify the corresponding node/tip for every species list [i] that you derived from your nexus tree:

```
PhyloNode[i]<-findMRCA(rootedtree, tips=Specieslist[i], type="node")
```

and derive which row in the matrix rootedtree$edge has this node/tip as offspring:

```
EdgeRow[i]<-which(rootedtree$edge[,2]==PhyloNode[i])
```

Please mind that i=1 needs to be excluded from this reference table, because the Nexus root does not exist in a phylo tree.
Once you identified the edge of every node, you can reorder your data

```
MapData<-mydata$seeds
names(MapData)<-EdgeRow
MapData<-MapData[order(ParentRow)]
plotBranchbyTrait(rootedtree, MapData, palette = "rainbow", mode="edges")
```